# How can I load true type front (ttf) into wxPython from file directly

Tags: python, wxpython, truetype, wxstyledtextctrl, richtextctrl

I'm working on a `wxPython` project with text editing capabilities. I want to package a font with this project `(a .ttf file)` and have it as the default font for the text editor. Can this be done in `wxPython`?  [There was a similar question](http://wxpython-users.1045709.n5.nabble.com/load-true-type-front-ttf-from-file-directly-td2358283.html) in 2007 in the `wxPython-users` mailing list. At that time it was not possible. It's now seven years later and I'm hoping that someone came up with a solution for this.

I am currently using `wx.richtextctr`l for the text editing box. I might consider using `wx.styledtextctrl` instead if it helps to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, wx can still only use fonts that are installed in the system.  If you distribute your project using an installer then it can install the font and your application can access it by its facename.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I am planning to use an installer eventually. I rely on monospace fonts and many of them are very ugly. I was hoping to distribute a nice monospace font with the project.

Answer (score 1):

wxpython 4.1 added the method

```
wx.Font.AddPrivateFont(path)
```

which allows the program to use fonts even if they aren't installed globally on the system

The [docs](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.Font.html#wx.Font.AddPrivateFont) add two important disclaimers

> - Under OS X this method actually doesn’t do anything other than check    for the existence of the file in the “Fonts” subdirectory of
>     the    application bundle “Resources” directory. You are responsible
>     for    actually making the font file available in this directory and
>     setting    ATSApplicationFontsPath to Fonts value in your Info.plist
>     file. See    also wx.StandardPaths.GetResourcesDir
> - Under MSW this method must be called before any wx.GraphicsContext    objects have been created, otherwise the private font won’t be usable 
>     from them.